# Randomizing registers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, 64-bit, inline-assembly

If certain conditions are not met I want to crash my program by jumping to a random location. I also want to randomize the registers by statements like

```
asm("rdtsc \n");
asm ("movq %rax, %r15 \n");
...
asm ("xor %rbp, %r13 \n");
...
```

Is there a better/stealthier method to do this? I am concerned, because `rdtsc` is not a frequent statement in programs. Calling it continually generates similar results too. Beside this, can I somehow clear/randomize the stack content too?

Comment: Make a stack unwinding code that randomize stack frames at each level...

Answer (score 3):

If you *just* want to crash, your random choice of destination *might* jump somewhere legal.  Just run the `ud2` instruction (`0F 0B`), which is guaranteed to cause an invalid-instruction exception (leading to SIGILL) on every future x86 CPU.  i.e. it's reserved, so no future instruction-set extension will ever use that two-byte sequence at the beginning of an instruction.

If you care about high-quality randomness to frustrate any potential backtrace or core dump, then call a random number generator to fill a buffer of random data (or just one 32bit random value which you repeat).  Fill all the registers with that garbage data.  In 32bit code, you could use a `popa` instruction to fill all the registers with that garbage data.  In 64bit mode, you have to load them manually.

Then scribble over the stack with that data, so your program eventually stops with a segfault when you try to write to an unmapped address (because you've gone outside the stack area).

You could do that scribbling with a `rep stosd` or something.

As far as "stealthier", you'll need to be much more elaborate about what your threat model is, and what you're trying to stop anyone from learning / doing.  i.e. defend against someone modifying your binary to not crash this way?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Peter Cordes suggestions, I would add that the OP wants to code responsible for this obfuscation to stay out of scope (*stealthier*).  The instruction causing the crash needs to be somewhere else, otherwise the obfuscation code will be obvious from a crash dump and the code will be easy to patch to remove the bomb.

A rather easy solution is to locate the `RET` opcode from a common library function such as `read` or `strlen` and JUMP there by pushing the address on the stack and executing a RET statement.  This solution is not perfect: advanced debuggers exist that store the execution trace and will be able to backtrack to the obfuscator from the crash location.  In order to defeat that, you may prefer to enter an infinite loop instead of crashing, but that loop can be easily found and removed.

You can also embed some complex code in your app that computes for a while by executing many different functions in a random manner and use that as a honey pot to jump to from the obfuscator.